# Change button background color in entire project in Android

Tags: android, xml, button, background, default

I'm making an Android app, but I cannot change the default background color of all buttons in the project.

The only way I can do it is by changing them one by one.

Is there any other way?

Comment: How many you have button?
just copy paste your xml text to get same background color button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set buttonStyle in your Theme.

like following:
(I assume that you use `AppCompat`)

In your style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        ...
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/YourButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- For preview -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/YourButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YourButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <!-- Set background -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_button_drawable</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
     ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Do I have to make any change on the button's xml?

Comment: Yes, there should be no need to change button's.